# Remember picture is positioned too high

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want a word in a normal paragraph to be later pointed at by a callout. The MWE below actually achieves this, except, the word is shifted up. What is an elegant way to solve this, so that the word sits normally in the sentence?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\nodeWord}[1]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node(#1){#1};}}

\begin{document}

Here is a \nodeWord{little} sentence. 

\tikz[remember picture]{\node [rectangle callout, fill=blue!30!white,overlay,callout absolute pointer={(little.south)},text centered, below left=of little] (A) {Hello};}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the `baseline` of the inline TikZ code to match the `base` anchor of the node you create by adding the option `baseline=(#1.base)`. You might also consider adding `inner xsep=0pt` to prevent the interword spacing from being disturbed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\nodeWord}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner xsep=0pt]{\node(#1){#1};}}

\begin{document}

Here is a \nodeWord{little} sentence. 

\tikz[remember picture]{\node [rectangle callout, fill=blue!30!white,overlay,callout absolute pointer={(little.south)},text centered, below left=of little] (A) {Hello};}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better solution that doesn't affect the spacing might be possible with `tikzmark`, but I'm not totally sure.